# Searching a continuous string for matches in Python

Tags: python, string, search

I am trying to search through a hex dump for matching hex strings, ie in testHexData.txt there might be-20F09FE520F09FE51CF09FE518F09FE514F09FE50000A0E10CF09FE508F09FE5CEFABEBA300B00007C000028700000284900A0E3CC0100EB080200EA8716A0E3020BA0E3010080E000D0A0E194499FE5000094E5000050E30200000AC20100EB044084E2F9FFFFEA10089FE5000090E5F00000E28716A0E30000
and in testHex.txt there would be strings that may or may not be in testHexData.txt, eg. 20F09FE, 518F09FE, FGG7988H and so on.

I found the following piece of code, which works when the data to be searched is in list format, i.e. 
pig
dog
cat
but not if the data to be searched is a continuous string. The code runs without any errors, but does not produce results. I'm sure the solution is a simple one, but I'm running around in circles trying to find it. I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thanks :)

```
file1 = set(line.strip() for line in open(r'C:\Python27\testHexData.txt'))

file2 = set(line.strip() for line in open(r'C:\Python27\testHex.txt'))

for line in file1 & file2:

    if line:

        print line
```

Comment: is it acceptable to match at same location (e.g. hex file #1 characters 30-35 matches with hex file #2 characters 30-35), or could they be at different locations in the hex files (e.g. hex file #1 characters 30-35 matches with hex file #2 characters 472-477)?

Comment: what output would you like? per line will not work if its all one line.

Comment: pztrick- the match could be anywhere in the file, and the actual file will be GBs in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to load the whole file in memory (not good if its big) or take it in chucks.  I adjusted the below to chuck it in 2000 sized segments.  Assuming you just want the output of what patterns are in the file

```
patterns = set(line.strip() for line in open(r'C:\Python27\testHex.txt'))
max_pattern_len = max([len(p) for p in patterns])
with open(r'C:\Python27\testHexData.txt') as hex_file:
    prev_segment_part = ''
    for segment in hex_file.read(2000):
         seg = prev_segment_part + segment
         for pattern in list(patterns):
            if pattern in seg:
                print "Found:", pattern
                patterns.remove(pattern)
         prev_segment_part = seg[-max_pattern_len:]
```

Comment: Thanks cmd, but again, although it runs without error, it does not produce any results...

Comment: @user2188291 adjusted for big file processing

Comment: cmd, you are a gentleman and a scholar! Or a lady. Either way, it works perfectly. The segment part was an issue I was aware of, but was going to attempt to solve in the next stage, so you've saved me even more head scratching! Thanks again! :)